# How to have child classes override a parent method but with collection of different element types as parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, overriding

I am not sure whether the way I designed the project was correct.

My child classes have similar logics (functions), hence I would like to extract those similar logics into the parent class, and make them extend the parent class.
However, although they have similar logic, they are dealing with Scala Collection of different element types: Map[String, String], Map[String, String], Map[Set[String], Set[String]], etc.

One simple example, and one of my failed approach:

```
abstract class Parent {
   def mainfunc(): String = {
        //logic
        func(Map[Any, Any])
    }

    def func(Map[Any, Any]): String

}

class Child1 {
    override def func(Map[String, String]): String = {
        //logic
    }
}

class Child3 {
    override def func(Map[String, Set[String]]): String = {
        //logic
    }
}

class Child3 {
    override def func(Map[Set[String], Set[String]]): String = {
        //logic
    }
}
```

I tried `Any` but I got this error: `Any does not match String: class String in package lang is a subclass of class Any in package scala`
The function `func` is necessary to be in the parent class, because some functions in the parent class require it.
Could there be something wrong with my project design?

Comment: Say you have it working, how are you going to call the methods?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because an `override` method must accept all possible values accepted by the method it is overriding. Otherwise you could call the abstract method with types that the overridden method doesn't support, breaking type safety. Since `func` in `Parent` takes `Map[Any, Any]` the overridden `func` in the children must also take `Map[Any, Any]`.

It might be possible to do something with `type` members in the `abstract class` but the details depend on how these classes are going to be used.